# correct way to represent data in JSON

Tags: java, json

I have the following bit of information used as key representation for data where the key is meant to be dynamic i.e. not hardcoded as FB and SB - it could be AB, CD, EF in another instance (i.e. neither the number of keys nor their names are static).  The initial version I have is as follows:

```
{"FB":"psOVGY55Rnkr3QHntSCQ==","SB":"oOUaYrIxAVixf5zfslGwvcy44g=="}
```

I think it needs to be something like this:

```
 [{"name: "FB", "value": "psOVGY55Rnkr3QHntSCQ==",}]
```

I would appreciate feedback (would be great if any down/close voters can answer the question in addition to close/down voting).  Thanks

**Update**

The reason I am inquiring is because currently, the "key" being passed is dynamic, not static so I cannot create a POJO with attributes FB, SB since these values will change per message.

Comment: For me it totally depends on how you're going to use it.  From the perspective of JSON it doesn't matter.  Use whichever is easier to code against.

Comment: @MattS how does one get the key name and its corresponding value during JSON deserialization (let's say using Java/Jackson) when it is structured as {"FB":"psOVGY55Rnkr3QHntSCQ==","SB":"oOUaYrIxAVixf5zfslGwvcy44g=="} i.e. with no key i.e. {"key":"FB", "value": "psOVGY55Rnkr3QHntSCQ=="} - if you need to create a POJO for deserialization and the current keys are dynamic, would it not make sense to explicitly define what is the attribute name

Comment: I still feel the second approach is a better way for anyone consuming the data than to try and process dynamic keys

Answer (score 1):

I got your question a little bit. 
It is the data format formed by arranging string values with special characters like, **{ }, [ ], ‘,’, ‘:’**. Arranging strings with these characters makes entire data meaningful. A String contains a collection of data and data inside JSON represented as **name-value** pairs.

Have a look at the below simple JSON string that represents information of keys.

```
“keys”   :[{
                “name” : “FB”,
                “number” : “psOVGY55Rnkr3QHntSCQ==”
                   },
               {
                “name” : “SB”,
                “number” : “”
               }]
```

Comment: my issue is this - the value currently is being passed as the key name, and those values (current key name) are dynamic i.e. they can change with each message - how does one correctly deserialize that object in Java i.e. I cannot create an attribute FB and SB in a POJO - FB/SB will not be present in each message

Comment: please go through this, you may find some solutions [link](https://trinitytuts.com/tips/get-dynamic-keys-from-json-data/)

Comment: thanks but I'm also trying to make the output easier for consumers to parse - using dynamic keys does not seem like the optimal/more sane approach but I appreciate the feedback